# How to write std::is_member_{object,function}_pointer for static members?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

The `<type_traits>` standard header defines metafunctions

```
template< class T >
struct is_member_object_pointer;

template< class T >
struct is_member_function_pointer;

template< class T >
struct is_member_pointer;
```

How, if possible, would one write a similar set of metafunctions for *static* member variables and functions? Why are these metafunctions not part of `<type_traits>` (or boost's equivalent)?

Comment: Pointers to static members are just regular pointers; there's no way to distinguish them and no point doing so.

Answer (score 3):

They are part of `<type_traits>` under the name of [`std::void_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t), since C++17. With that you check whether a specific class type has a member variable and/or functions.

For example to check if a class type `Type` has a member object `x` you would use something like:

```
template<class, class = std::void_t<>>
struct has_x : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct has_x<T, std::void_t<decltype( std::declval<T&>().x )>> : std::true_type {};
```

and similarly for a member function `x()` you would use:

```
template<class, class = std::void_t<>>
struct has_x_mem_fn : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct has_x_mem_fn<T, std::void_t<decltype( std::declval<T&>().x() )>> : std::true_type {};
```

Comment: Rereading your question I have  a feeling this is not what you were asking for. Right?

Comment: Maybe that will work: `..has_x_mem_fn<T, std::void_t<decltype( T::x() )>...` for static member functions?